# Prototype and jQuery conflict with $.when.apply

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried multiple combination of usage of code to make the Prototype and jQuery to work, but no luck yet.

Here is what I have currently.

index.html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.2.0/prototype.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="MAIN_JS_FILE.js"></script>`
```

main_js_file.js:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var jsq = [];
        jsq.push(AJAX_CALL_FOR_FETCHING_JS_FILE_1);
        jsq.push(AJAX_CALL_FOR_FETCHING_JS_FILE_2);
        jsq.push(AJAX_CALL_FOR_FETCHING_JS_FILE_3);

        var deferredjs = jQuery.when.apply(jQuery, jsq);
        deferredjs.done(function() {
            //Various variable initialization
            //Various function definition.
        }
    });
```

Now when page is loaded (page loads properly), chrome console shows an error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

When clicked on the error file link, it points to `element.dispatchEvent(event);` in the prototype.js file, line no 7066.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

**Edit:** I have changed the `MAIN_JS_FILE.js` file to use only `jQuery` instead of `$`
So now there is not a single javascript code that uses `$` and still the `undefined` error is displayed.

If I now use `jQuery.noConflict();` before `.ready()` function, then the `$.when.apply` code does not even execute.

Comment: have you looked into [jQuery noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Comment: That means you're using prototype somewhere, and it doesn't look like the error is in the posted code. Does it say what line the error is on.

Comment: @steveniseki - He's already using it, in the form of a closure.

Comment: (1) `jQuery.noConflict` is your friend; (2) I really don't understand why people should include two libs that do similar things.

Comment: @adeneo it should be working okay then with jQuery noConflict, as you say the posted code looks okay

Comment: @steveniseki - prototype.js doesn't overwrite `jQuery`, and the OP is using a IIFE to lock in the value and set the dollarsign. One generally doesn't need `$.noConflict` these days, all you should need is an IIFE like the one the OP is using.

Comment: Please check my edit. If no `jQuery.noConflict();`, then the error is dislayed. If used, then the `jQuery.when.apply` code does not execute. Where exactly should the `jQuery.noConflict();` code be written? As for the reason of using 2 libs is that the website uses prototype already and the widget loaded on the page uses jQuery.

Comment: In Chrome you can go up the stack trace to see where the call that generates the `undefined` error originates from - can you try that to find the culprit?

Answer (score 1):

As `@steven iseki` mentioned in comment you, can use [`jQuery.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/). You can read on their website that:

> Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so all functionality is available without using $.

And it's indeed a case with `Prototype` also using `$` sign.

Also, remember to use `jQuery` instead of `$` sign in your jQuery code, e.g.:

```
jQuery(selector).on('click', function(){...});
```

Comment: Now, I am using `jQuery` throughout the code. Still the `undefined` error is displayed. If I use `jQuery.noConflict();` at the top in the `MAIN_JS_FILE.js`, then the code within `jQuery.when.apply` does not even execute.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's `jQuery Conflict` error here. Try changing your code from `main.js`. Try alternate method to get your task done here. I analyzed your code but `prototype.js` has a way of hiding real thing.